# AG-Grid: How to exclude selected rows from setQuickFilter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

My AG-Grid table utilizes [`setQuickFilter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-quick/) to filter rows by user input search criteria. The grid also has [`rowSelection`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/) enabled for other actions. My goal is to exclude selected rows from the search filter so that they always render in the grid regardless of what data the user is searching.

I attempted to conditionally call `setQuickFilter` only on unselected rows, but `setQuickFilter` is a method on the grid API and applies to all row data (e.g. `gridApi.setQuickFilter(data)`)

I also attempted to use [`isExternalFilterPresent` and `doesExternalFilterPass`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-external/) to add my own filtering logic, but these appear to only run on the initial grid render rather than dynamically updating when selected rows and/or search filters update.

Is this type of filtering possible with current grid capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Posting a working solution in case it is helpful to anyone that runs into this scenario. Using `setQuickFilter()` comes with a getter as well: [`getQuickFilterText()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-quick/#reference-filter-getQuickFilter). Keeping track of the search value in a `useRef` in tandem with this getter function can help differentiate the search value from selected rows.

```
const getQuickFilterText = (params) => {
  if (params.node.isSelected()) {
    return searchRef.current;
  }
  return params.searchValue;
}
```

The getter function is then passed into one of the column defs.